# Advanced filter for subscription to multiple tags

Tags: feature-request

Could we have some advanced filters for subscribing to multiple tags? For example, I want to subscribe to "[classical-mechanics] AND [lagrangian-mechanics]" (I'm talking about a logical AND operation) but not to either of them individually.

Also, I'd like to subscribe to specific keywords if possible. Thanks.

Comment: These tool are provided by the underling Stack Exchange engine, and [should be discussed on the mother meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ignored-tags+favorite-tags). (That's meta.StackOverflow for now, but will be meta.StackExchange in the usual six to eight weeks.)